# MongoDB Aggregation, is there a way to get executionStats from an aggregate cursor?

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDB 3.0.4 and i have a database with data which i want to aggregate. The problem, it takes way longer than it should. I did my homework (at least to a minimum i guess), i saw the function `explain()` and lots of tips about aggregation and indexes optimization but even so, i'm still doubtful.

What annoys me the most is that i can't use the `explain()` function properly on aggregate cursor. There is of course the option you can pass directly to the aggregate function but it does not allow you to change the verbosity.

I can use `find().explain("executionStats")`. It works. I also used the option to force the aggregate to return a cursor. Yet i couldn't do anything in the form of:

```
db.coll.aggregate( ... { cursor : { batchSize : 0}}).explain("executionStats")
```

or

```
var a = db.coll.aggregate( ... { cursor : { batchSize : 0}})
a.explain("executionStats")
```

In the other hand:

```
db.coll.explain("executionStats").aggregate( ... )
```

works but uses the wrong level of verbosity and i can't get the information i want...

So, the actual query is:

```
db.pmsi.aggregate([
{ $match : { $GHM_Obtenu : { $in : ["040M51", "04M052"] } } },
{ $project : { "_id" : 0, "$GHM_Obtenu" : 1 } },
{ $group : {
    _id : { "$GHM_Obtenu" },
    count : { $sum : 1 } }
}
],{
    cursor : { batchSize : 0 }
})
```

There is an index on the field "GHM_Obtenu" for those who wonder.

Anyway, the question remains:
Is there a way to get the `executionStats` from an aggregate request?

I thank you for taking the time to read my question and i hope i didn't missed something too obvious.

Cheers !

Comment: I think what you are missing here is that the same "ms" response as is shown from a query execution plan does not really apply to an aggregation pipeline. As it is in fact using the "same engine" to do so, then all that can really be looked at is the initial `$match` phase ( where one is present ) to determine the efficiency of that query result. The additional pipeline stages are not similarly "timed" as this does not correlate to actions with the normal query engine. Whilst it might be "nice" to see the timings of each stage, such a thing does not yet exist.

Comment: @BlakesSeven i understand what you're saying but i'm not looking for the executionStats for the execution timings, i'm concerned by the memory usage and notably the numbers of docs examinated. Still, thank you :)

Comment: Hence, you get those results by just running the same basic query with `.find().explain()` as what you are running in your initial `$match`. It's not a idle comment, I was telling you what the explain output is. Just a query analysis and nothing else to do with the rest of the pipeline execution.

Comment: But if I aggregate and group on $first, a proper index would in theory at least allow not have to examine all documents and a whole-aggregate executionStats would be worthwhile. Or is this not possible with MongoDB?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB get executionStats for aggregate query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39917073/mongodb-get-executionstats-for-aggregate-query)

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it on version 3.4. I used db.setProfilingLevel(2)
Then I got the stats I needed in the system.profile() collection.

It was the only way I found to get things like the "docsExamined" that are gotten with explain("executionStats") on newer versions.

Answer (score 1):

For mongodb 5.0.0+, just using `db.collections.explain('executionStats').aggregate([])`.

If there are still **NO** executionStats, just change your mongodb client.
When I switch DataGrip to mongosh, executionStats appear!

Answer (score -1):

From mongodb [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#return-information-on-aggregation-pipeline-operation), you can run an {explain: true} as option for aggregation.

```
db.collection.aggregate(pipeline, options)¶
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. As of version 3.4, this won't return any `executionStats` but only regular simple explain.