# MongoDB get executionStats for aggregate query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am looking for a way to retrieve the `executionStats` for aggregations.

When using find(), I can retrieve them easily by using [explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/).
Example output:

```
  "executionStats": {
    "nReturned": 332505,
    "executionTimeMillis": 1349,
    "totalKeysExamined": 332505,
    "totalDocsExamined": 332505,
    ...
```

But when using [aggregations with explain enabled](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#return-information-on-aggregation-pipeline-operation) it won't return the stats shown above.

[This](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-6306) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31970636/mongodb-aggregation-is-there-a-way-to-get-executionstats-from-an-aggregate-curs) is related but there is no viable solution given. Because this might have changed in the meantime, I opened this question.

Is there any way this can be done without measuring the stats on the client side?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Updated Answer:**

From MonogoDB version 3.5.5, `executionStats` and `allPlansExecution` modes are supported in explain method with aggregation.

```
db.users.explain("executionStats").aggregate([]);
```

As per [mongodb doc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#return-information-on-aggregation-pipeline-operation),
`You can view more verbose explain output by passing the executionStats or allPlansExecution explain modes to the db.collection.explain() method.`

**Old Answer:**

Currently(MongoDB 3.2) aggregation does not support executionStats, with explain option in aggreagation you get some data related to query but there is no executionStats in it. It is proposed and you can check its status here

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-19758

Please upvote the issue if you want to implement this soon.

Comment: Is there any bypass to it or is the measuring the data on the application side the only way currently?

Comment: I am also searching that, if i find any way to that will update here.

Comment: you may update your answer as mongodb executionStats is now supported in aggregation pipeline

Answer (score 6):

For me it works like this, you have this fixed in from version 3.5.5

It shows the execution plan and other metrics.

```
db.videos.explain('executionStats').aggregate([])
```

[image]

Comment: `The 'explain' option is illegal when a explain verbosity is also provided` in mongodb `4.0.13`

Comment: Now isn't work, I using python3.10 with pymongo

Answer (score 5):

I was able to do it in the following way:

```
db.myUserCollection.explain("executionStats").aggregate([{$match: {firstName: "John"} }]);
```

Reference: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-19758

Comment: This doesn't help much its almost equal to the `explain`

Answer (score 1):

executionStats was not supported for mongo aggregation queries till mongodb v3.4. The issue has been fixed in v3.6.
i.e. `db.videos.explain('executionStats').aggregate([])`

Answer (score 0):

For mongodb 5.0.0+, just like other answers said, just using `db.collections.explain('executionStats').aggregate([])`.

If there are **NO** executionStats, just change your mongodb client.
When I switch DataGrip to mongosh, executionStats appear!